# in_array() -- What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php

I'm banging my head against the wall here.

I have some simple code that goes something like this (I've simplified it greatly for simplicity's sake):

```
$myValue = 1;

$myArray[0] = 2;
$myArray[1] = 3;
$myArray[2] = 1;

if(in_array($myValue, $myArray, true)) {
   do something;
}
else {
   do something else;
}
```

I always get the 'else.' Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What does `var_dump($myValue, $myArray);` show you?  The `true` in `in_array` tells it to use `===` instead of `==`.  My guess is you are trying to compare different types, like strings vs ints.

Comment: Missing `}` , maybe. Otherwise I can't reproduce it: https://3v4l.org/WrRoa

Comment: You have error reporting turned on?

Comment: @Rizier123 I forgot the bracket in my example code above. The real code has the bracket in place. Thanks for looking so closely, though.

Comment: "If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the in_array() function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack." - are you sure that you compare same types?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - it doesn't, i've read it wrong.

Comment: @RocketHazmat -- I tried doing this:

$myValue = intval(1);

$array[x] = intval(1);

Still no luck, though. However, the function DOES work when I turn off strict mode.

Comment: @Duplosion, i am 99% sure that you compare strings with integers, or something like it... check your real array values (actually their types), and you will see... When third parametar is set to true -> types must be the same, too, check this: https://eval.in/427628 and try to run codes...

Comment: A var_dump() of both $myValue and $myArray shows that both values are integers. This is weird.

Comment: I agree, edit question and add your real code, if possible. :)

Comment: @Diplusion: Remove 'psudeo code' and write your original code. Don't keep post as simple.

Comment: *A var_dump() of both $myValue and $myArray shows that both values are integers.*... $myArray should be an array of integers otherwise you will get *Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given*

Answer (score 0):

It will return "Yes". Do & else are PHP keyword. Echo Something.. It Will Come

```
<?
$myValue = 1;

$myArray[0] = 2;
$myArray[1] = 3;
$myArray[2] = 1;

if(in_array($myValue, $myArray, true)) 
{
   echo "Yes";
}
else 
{
   echo "No";
}
?>
```

Otherwise, if you use 'do' or 'else' keyword, 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting while (T_WHILE)
error will come.

For more info, read this http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp

Comment: `do something;` and `do something else;` were presumably just pseudo-code and not what's *really* in his file.  He says `I always get the 'else.'` which means his code contains valid syntax.

Comment: Mr @RocketHazmat. I Talk & Work Practically. I Checked The Above Code. It Didn't Worked Just Because Of 'do something;' & 'do something else;'. As, i removed it with 'echo', It worked fine.

Comment: And, @RocketHazmat, Why i'm not getting else part after removing "do something.." lines from the code.. Why it is working fine for me after removing those lines..

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's correct. It's pseudo-code. I wanted to keep my post as simple as possible.

Comment: Ok @Duplosion, Then remove those psudeo codes for 15 second and use echo "". If you again come to else.. then tell me again.